# How to implement strategy design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

Can anyone tell how can we implement Strategy design pattern in the following code. I have gone through various links but not fully clear about implementing it.
Question is: Calculate points and display the report in PDF or HTML  using Strategy Design Pattern.
Below is the code already available. Customer, Movie and Rental are classes already created:

1. Customer.java

   ```
    public class Customer {
    private String _name;
    private Vector _rentals = new Vector();
    public Customer(String name) {
    _name = name;
    };

    public void addRental(Rental arg) {
    _rentals.addElement(arg);
    }

    public String getName() {
    return _name;
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Customer c = new Customer("ABC");
    Movie m = new Movie("Title", 1);
    Rental r = new Rental(m, 10);
    c.addRental(r);
    // Rental calculation
    String s = c.statement();
    System.out.println("s: " + s);
   }
        public String statement() {
        double totalAmount = 0;
    int frequentRenterPoints = 0;
    Enumeration rentals = _rentals.elements();
    String result = "Rental Record for " + getName() + "\n";

    while (rentals.hasMoreElements()) {
        double thisAmount = 0;
        Rental each = (Rental) rentals.nextElement();

        // determine amounts for each line
        switch (each.getMovie().getPriceCode()) {

        case Movie.REGULAR:
            thisAmount += 2;
            if (each.getDaysRented() > 2)
                thisAmount += (each.getDaysRented() - 2) * 1.5;
            break;

        case Movie.NEW_RELEASE:
            thisAmount += each.getDaysRented() * 3;
            break;

        case Movie.CHILDRENS:
            thisAmount += 1.5;
            if (each.getDaysRented() > 3)
                thisAmount += (each.getDaysRented() - 3) * 1.5;
            break;
        } // add frequent
            // renter points
        frequentRenterPoints++;

        // add bonus for a two day new release rental
        if ((each.getMovie().getPriceCode() == Movie.NEW_RELEASE) && each.getDaysRented() > 1)
            frequentRenterPoints++;

        // show figures for this rental
        result += "\t" + each.getMovie().getTitle() + "\t" + String.valueOf(thisAmount) + "\n";
        totalAmount += thisAmount;
    }

    // add footer lines
    result += "Amount owed is " + String.valueOf(totalAmount) + "\n";
    result += "You earned " + String.valueOf(frequentRenterPoints) + " frequent renter points";
    return result;
    }
    }
   ```
2. Movie.java

   ```
   public class Movie {
   public static final int CHILDRENS = 2;
   public static final int REGULAR = 0;
   public static final int NEW_RELEASE = 1;
   private String _title;
   private int _priceCode;

    public Movie(String title, int priceCode) {
   _title = title;
   _priceCode = priceCode;
   }
   public int getPriceCode() {
       return _priceCode;
   }

   public void setPriceCode(int arg) {
   _priceCode = arg;
   }
   public String getTitle() {
   return _title;
   };
   }
   ```
3. Rental.java

   ```
   public class Rental {
       private Movie _movie;
   private int _daysRented;
   public Rental(Movie movie, int daysRented) {
       _movie = movie;
   _daysRented = daysRented;
   }
   public int getDaysRented() {
       return _daysRented;
   }
       public Movie getMovie() {
       return _movie;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Comment: `interface Strategy{ int process(int a, int b)}; then Strategy x= (a,b) -> a*b` Entire functional interfaces are based on Strategy

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: Yes, but this is the problem statement and the code given. Code has to be improved and implemented Strategy design pattern.

Comment: @emotionlessbananas: I face issues in implementing a concept on a particular code/problem, so need the changes in above code accordingly,

Comment: Where do *you* think you're meant to apply the strategy pattern?

Comment: public class MovieType implements MovieTypeInterface {
 Movie getMovieType(Movie movie, int movieEnum) {
 Movie m = null;
 if (movieEnum == Constants.CHILDRENS) {
   m = new Childrens(movie.getTitle(), movie.getPriceCode());
  }
  if (movieEnum == Constants.REGULAR) {
   m = new Regular(movie.getTitle(), movie.getPriceCode());
  }
  if (movieEnum == Constants.NEW_RELEASE) {
   m = new NewRelease(movie.getTitle(), movie.getPriceCode());
  }
  return m;
 }
 public Movie getMovie(Movie movie, int moviePriceCode) {
  return new MovieType().getMovieType(movie, moviePriceCode);
 }
}

Comment: public interface MovieTypeInterface {
 Movie getMovieType(Movie movie, int movieEnum);
}

I have modified my code a bit and used Inteface. And according to the movieEnum, Class will be called (Regular, New_Release or Childrens)

Comment: Here strategy will be implemented when you are printing reports, as they can be dynamic and so far best use case for strategy.

Comment: Too bad they didn't tell you *why* you should use the strategy pattern.  The opportunity that jumps out from the code it to replace the price code with a pricing strategy that calculates a price from a number of days.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is "display the report in PDF or HTML using Strategy Design Pattern", so strategy will be applied here.
Before display Report you should have all computed data (keep the work as was done) and after just pass data and choose appropriate report type.

```
public interface IReport 
{
    public void printReport(String data);
}
```

```
public class ReportHTML implements IReport
{
    @Override
    public void printReport(String data) {
        System.out.println("Html Report with data="+data);  
    }
}
```

```
public class ReportPDF implements IReport{
    @Override
    public void printReport(String data) {
        System.out.println("PDF Report with data="+data);   
    }
}
```

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //do whatever computation concerning business logic
        //after for print pass computed data and chose report type as needed
        IReport ir = new ReportHTML();
        ir.printReport("[Customers, Movie, Rental]");
        ir = new ReportPDF();
        ir.printReport("[Customers, Movie, Rental]");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Html Report with data=[Customers, Movie, Rental]
PDF Report with data=[Customers, Movie, Rental]
```

Comment: `how about IReport report = r-> System.out.println(r); r.printReport("Some Data);`

Comment: @emotionlessbananas implementation it's up to him, but i doubt that in a real scenarios 1 line of code will be enough or even use something ad-hoc

Comment: look at java 8 predicate

Comment: @emotionlessbananas kindly read again previous comment and maybe you could figured out what is the meaning ...

Answer (score 0):

HTML and PDF are display formats. A strategy is just a pluggable algorithm, usually defined by an interface. Since the task is to display the report and the pluggable part is how to display it (the algorithm), you need a display strategy. As for names, many people would call the interface ReportDisplayStrategy and that’s fine, but often I think the design pattern name is just pollution, so I’d consider something more like ReportRenderer. If the output is always a file (there’s a lot more you could do here), the interface might look like:

```
interface ReportRenderer
{ 
    File render(Report report)
}
```

The rest is matter of making your report object and writing the renderer implementations for PDF and HTML.